# Как через Java управлять ScrollView?

Tags: android, textview, scrollview

Добрый день! У меня есть две `button` и один `textview` в `ScrollView`. При нажатии на `button` меняется текст. Но проблема в том, что когда нажимаешь на `button1`, затем прокручиваешь текст, а после нажимаешь `button2`, то новый текст открывается на том месте, как будто прокручивали не первый текст, а и этот тоже. Нужно чтобы он открывался с самого начала, а не зависел от того, насколько пользователь прокрутил первый текст.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно прокрутить scrollView в верхнее положение, то попробуй так:

```
buttonScrollToTop.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myScroll.scrollTo(0, 0);
        }
    });
```